# Django: Render html tag inside bootstrap modal

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add markdown to my Django app and it works, but not when the test is displayed inside a bootstrap modal.

I use markdown2 to render the text and a custom templatetag like this:

```
{{ issue.description | markdown | safe }}
```

Any suggestion about how to do it work inside a modal?

I show the modal using AJAX call:

```
$(".js-view-issue").click(function() {
  var btn = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: btn.attr("data-url"),
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#viewIssue").modal("show");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#viewIssue .modal-content").html(data.html);
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit**

Here modals/view_issue.html file:

```
{% load markdown_tag %}

<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewIssueLabel">View Issue</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aira-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Title</strong></label>
    <input class="form-control" value="{{ issue.title }}" disabled />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Description</strong></label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" disabled>{{ issue.description | markdown | safe }}</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Solution</strong></label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" disabled>{{ issue.solution | markdown }}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the response of the ajax call?

Comment: `data['html'] = render_to_string('modals/view_issue.html', context, request=request)`

Comment: Please add `modals/view_issue.html`.